# How to capitalise a letter in a custom snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I am trying to create a snippet using vs code (javascript.json) to do the following code.

```
const [click, setClick] = useState(false)
```

I have created the following snippet which sort of works.

```
    "My Custom useState": {
    "prefix": "myus",
    "body": [
        "const [${1:name}, set${1:name}] = useState(${2|true,false|})"
    ],
    "description": "My Custom useState"
}
```

But in the example, I want to try and find a way to capitalise the second word. So the above snippet output is

```
const [click, setclick] = useState(false)
```

Currently, I go back into the code and change to a capital letter by hand, but it has reduced the amount of code I write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as the body:

`"const [${1:name}, set${1/(.)/${1:/capitalize}/}] = useState(${2|true,false|})"`

That will "transform" the first letter `(.)` of that capture group 1 into a capital letter `${1:/capitalize}`.

In your case `${1:/upcase}` would do the same thing since the capture group only contains the first letter.  Normally, `${1:/upcase}` will capitalize the entire capture group, not just the first letter like `${1:/capitalize}` does.

What will not work is `set${1:name/(.)/${1:/capitalize}/}` where the default `:name` is used.  You cannot transform a default.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/56703

Comment: I copied the suggested code into my javascript.json and then typed the prefix "myus" and the snippet did what I was trying to achieve. Great answer and very helpful. Thanks